# Bootstrap 3 Navbar like Twitter Navbar now

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, navigation, navbar

I want to create a navigation bar like a navigation bar twitter today. But I found the problem when it is in the navigation bar menu on hover, there are few areas that cross the line of the high navigation and **I want to close the border down text menus**. The code that I have created using the Bootstrap 3, are you can fix it so that it looks like the navigation bar twitter today?

My CSS:

```css
body {
   background-color: #ecedee;
}
#container {
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   background: #fff;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   -o-border-radius: 0;
 }

 .navbar-brand {
   position: relative;
   padding: 21px 25px 21px 25px;
   margin: 0!important;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   color: #1c1c1c;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
   margin-right: 0px!important;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
margin-left: 5px;
   }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #1c1c1c;
   display: block;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 200;
   padding: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #1c1c1c;
  }
```

and this is my detail **code** [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ramadani/SL3YF/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this example ; http://jsbin.com/fosulida/1/ , I added borders with background color to non active links